# Using valueForKey to convert array of strings to array of nsnumbers

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I have an array of strings containing numbers. So if there was a method to get `NSNumber` from `NSString` it would be easy to get an array of numbers with:

```
[arrayOfStrings valueForKey:@"NSNumberValue"]
```

But to convert string to number you have to do something like this:

```
[NSNUmber numberWithInt:[string intValue]];
```

I wonder if there's any way to do this without manually iterating through arrays?

Comment: [[arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex: index] intValue]

Comment: @BHASKAR "without manually iterating through arrays"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSArray *arrayOfNumbers = [arrayOfStrings valueForKey:@"intValue"];`

Comment: +1. To explain: the question assumes you need a property of `NSString` which has type `NSNumber*`. However, KVC will wrap scalar numeric types in `NSNumber` objects for you automatically. So, you just need a property with a scalar numeric type, like `-intValue`.

Comment: Exactly. After all, `valueForKey:` is known to work with scalar properties as well and given that it returns `id` it's implicit that scalar types are automatically wrapped.